# why does a basic javascript code is not exiting from a basic condition How can i write it in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in js and jquery coding environment. my question is why does my does not exit after the condition gets false.
i want this function to run once ?
How can this be written in jquery?
thanks in advance.

```js
//document.getElementById("generate_otp").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var i = 0;
  if (i < 1) {
    var a1 = document.getElementById("generate_otp");
    var html = '<br/><br/><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter OTP" name="" maxlength="6" required></div></div></div><input type="button" name="enter_otp"id="enter_otp" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" />';
    //document.getElementById("generate_otp").innerHTML = html;
    a1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', html);
    i++;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="generate_otp" id="generate_otp" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Get OTP" />
```

Comment: Declare `i` outside of `myFunction`?

Comment: actually, it does exit

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any loops here

Comment: Where's the loop exactly?

Comment: It is not at all clear from the question, but what I _think_ you're asking, is "How to get the onclick handler to only fire the first time". Is that correct?

Comment: yes, why does onclick , new tags appears everytime

Answer (score 1):

As @CertainPerformance suggested declare and initialize `i` outside of `myFunction`

```js
var i = 0;

function myFunction() {  
  if (i < 1) {
    var a1 = document.getElementById("generate_otp");
    var html = '<br/><br/><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter OTP" name="" maxlength="6" required></div></div></div><input type="button" name="enter_otp"id="enter_otp" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" />';
    //document.getElementById("generate_otp").innerHTML = html;
    a1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', html);
    i++;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="generate_otp" id="generate_otp" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Get OTP" />
```

Comment: But still: there’s no loop in this snippet

Comment: thanks, how can i write this in jquery